# How can a ham from a non-CEPT country operate in Canada?

Tags: legal, canada, australia

Long time maritime operator now semi-retired and messin' about with radios. Family in NL and want to bring my little QRP 40-meter rig this summer. I'd like to operate in Canada, specifically VO1 while shooting some video. Will also be sailing on a friend's sailboat. Last trip home I talked to the operators at Signal Hill and have made some contacts. In 1997 I was reporting for Radio Australia and Australian Broadcasting Commission for the Matthew and Queen's visit for the 500 years. I sailed with the flotilla from Royal NL Yacht Club to Bonavista for the welcome.

Because my home country Australia is not a CEPT country, I'm a bit unsure about how to get legal permission to operate in Canada.  Do I need a Canadian license?  What should I do to get started?

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Because of our question-and-answer format, we greatly favor specific questions.  In an attempt to help, I edited your question to be more specific.  I hope I didn't change what you meant!  Please feel free to reject my edit or make more changes.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/025.nsf/eng/h_00006.html#tao4:

'...you must bring your amateur radio operator’s certificate/licence and have obtained a CEPT certificate from your home administration. **If your country is not part of the CEPT agreement you must obtain a letter of authority from the [Amateur Radio Service Centre (ARSC)](https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/025.nsf/eng/h_00010.html)**. Visiting amateurs must include the prefix of the geographical location, and the area of operation with the identification of their station. Therefore, an amateur from the United Kingdom with the call sign G**** who will be operating in Winnipeg, Manitoba, would append the prefix “Portable VE4” or “/VE4” to their home call sign, and transmit “Winnipeg” at least once during each communication.'

In short: to get started, send an email to ic.spectrumamateur-spectreamateur.ic@canada.ca and they should tell you how to proceed.